# Python on Gitlab has ModuleNotFound, But Not When I Run Locally

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, python-import, modulenotfounderror

The following snapshot shows the file structure:
[image]

When I run on Gitlab CI, here is what I am seeing:

[image: Gitlab output]

Why is this error occurring when Gitlab runs it but not when I run locally?

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Note that this had been working before.
I recently made `win_perf_counters` a Git submodule instead of being an actual subdirectory.  (Again, it works locally.)

```
test:
  before_script:
    - python -V
    - pip install virtualenv
    - virtualenv venv
    - .\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
    - refreshenv
  script:
  - python -V
  - echo "******* installing pip ***********"
  - python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  - echo "******* installing locust ********"
  - python -m pip install locust
  - locust -V
  - python -m pip install multipledispatch
  - python -m pip install pycryptodome
  - python -m pip install pandas
  - python -m pip install wmi
  - python -m pip install pywin32
  - python -m pip install influxdb_client
  - set LOAD_TEST_CONF=load_test.conf
  - echo "**** about to run locust ******"
  - locust -f ./src/main.py --host $TARGET_HOST -u $USERS -t $TEST_DURATION -r $RAMPUP -s 1800 --headless --csv=./LoadTestsData_VPOS --csv-full-history --html=./LoadTestsReport_VPOS.html  --stream-file ./data/stream_jsons/streams_vpos.json --database=csv
  
    
  - Start-Sleep -s $SLEEP_TIME

  variables:
    LOAD_TEST_CONF: load_test.conf
    PYTHON_VERSION: 3.8.0
    TARGET_HOST: http://10.10.10.184:9000

  tags:
    - win2019
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./LoadTests*
      - public
  only:
    - schedules

  after_script:
    - ls src -r
    - mkdir .public
    - cp -r ./LoadTests* .public
    - cp metrics.csv .public -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    - mv .public public
```

When I tried with changing the Gitlab CI file to use `requirements.txt`:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the module you are developing doesn't have the __init__.py file and thus it cannot be found when imported from the external.

Comment: Hi @Flavio, and welcome.  Could you please be a bit more specific, like what you mean by "module you are developing"?   Also, what do you think the __init__ file should contain?    I still get an error, and I have tried various "import" statements after creating the __init__ file.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the python libraries you are using in your local environment are not the same you are using in gitlab. Run a `pip list` or `pip freeze` in your local machine and see which versions do you have there. Then pip install those in your gitlab script. A good practice is to have a requirements.txt or a setup.py file with specific versions rather than pulling the latest versions every time.

Comment: I'll paste the results of trying run with requirements.txt (I have one)  I resulted in many build errors.